# Get two terms (values) from a form in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I want to run an AJAX script witch queries my database based on two parameters.
That is the form I've got

```
<form id="search-box" action="search.php"  method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="31" placeholder="username ..." />
      /
      <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" size="31" placeholder="surname..." />
      <input type="submit" id="submit-button" name="sa" value="search" />
</form>
```

That is the java script for the AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {     
    $("#surname").autocomplete({
        source: "ajax-user.php",
        minLength: 2,
    });
});
</script>
```

And that is the php for the which does the query

```
 <?php
require_once('connection.php');

try {
  $conn = new readPDO("test");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$return_arr = array();

if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $ac_term2 = "%".$_GET['term2']."%";
    $query = "
            SELECT 
                surname
            FROM 
                worker
            WHERE 
                lower(username)
                LIKE lower(:term)
                AND
                lower(surname)
                LIKE lower(:term2)
            ";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->bindValue(":term2",$ac_term2);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['value'] = $row['repoName'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}
/* Free connection resources. */
$conn = null; 
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

So what I was not able to do is to get $ac_term2 value passed. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to add `jquery` and `autocomplete` tags

Comment: So this would be 
$("#username").autocomplete({
        source: "ajax-user.php",
        minLength: 2,
    });

But then how my php would look like? 
$ac_term2 = ?
$ac_term = ?

Comment: You have to add `jquery` and `autocomplete` tags **to the question**. Since it more related to `autocomplete` plugin than `AJAX`

Comment: oh, sorry, I don't understand you.. thank you.